# Regsvr32 : The dll file was loaded but the DLLRegistryServer Entry Point was not found

Tags: vb.net, dll, registry, regsvr32

I have ported my code from vb6 to vs 2005. Build is running fine. After installing the exe of my project.
The dll file was loaded but the DLLRegistryServer Entry Point was not found.

Comment: Which DLL causes this error?

Comment: DLLs created by VB.NET do not support, nor require, registration.  All that your installer has to do is copy the file.

Comment: its the dll that has been generaed from my code.